# Crop com html/css/js

Tags: javascript, html

Estou tentando usar um plugin que achei [neste vídeo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pVatkCgU-Rg), porém estou enfrentando o seguinte problema: gostaria de fazer upload de uma imagem e fazer um crop em 1747px de largura. Porém para dispositivos com largura menor que isto acaba explodindo como na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém sabe como resolver isto? Código abaixo.

```css
#uploadimageModal .modal-dialog {
    max-width: 1920px !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/croppie/2.6.2/croppie.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/croppie/2.6.2/croppie.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
          <br />
      <h3 align="center">Image Crop & Upload using JQuery with PHP Ajax</h3>
      <br />
      <br />
   <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">Select Profile Image</div>
      <div class="panel-body" align="center">
       <input type="file" name="upload_image" id="upload_image" accept="image/*" />
       <br />
       <div id="uploaded_image"></div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div id="uploadimageModal" class="modal" role="dialog">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Upload & Crop Image</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="row">
       <div class="col-12 text-center">
        <div id="image_demo" style="margin-top:30px"></div>
       </div>
       <div class="col-12" style="padding-top:30px;">
        <button class="btn btn-success crop_image">Crop & Upload Image</button>
     </div>
    </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
     </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>  
$(document).ready(function(){

 $image_crop = $('#image_demo').croppie({
    enableExif: true,
    viewport: {
      width:1747,
      height:800,
      type:'square' //circle
    },
    boundary:{
      width:1847,
      height:846
    }
  });

  $('#upload_image').on('change', function(){
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (event) {
      $image_crop.croppie('bind', {
        url: event.target.result
      }).then(function(){
        console.log('jQuery bind complete');
      });
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
    $('#uploadimageModal').modal('show');
  });

  $('.crop_image').click(function(event){
    $image_crop.croppie('result', {
      type: 'canvas',
      size: 'viewport'
    }).then(function(response){
      $.ajax({
        url:"upload.php",
        type: "POST",
        data:{"image": response},
        success:function(data)
        {
          $('#uploadimageModal').modal('hide');
          $('#uploaded_image').html(data);
        }
      });
    })
  });

});  
</script>
```

Comment: Já tentou colocar a imagem com width em %, tipo max-width: 100% para ver como fica?

Comment: A imagem em si não é o problema, adicionado o 100% ela se adapta ao container, o problema é que tem uma div pai, onde é o tamanho definido no js como viewport e outra div que é definida como boundary, acredito ser nessas divs que deve ser feito algo para a imagem se adaptar.

Answer (score 2):

Cara eu fiz um ajuste no código, primeiro coloquei no JS a largura `$image_crop` no `viewport` e `boundary` em 100%.

Depois determinei pro modal uma largura máxima com `max-width`, mas para menos que isso eu tb declarei o `width` em 100%, isso via deixar a janela responsiva para telas pequenas.

O resultado foi esse:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código da imagem acima:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title>Page Title</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
    html,
    body {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }


    #uploadimageModal .modal-dialog {
        width: 90%;
        max-width: 922px !important;
    }

</style>
</head>

<body>

    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/croppie/2.6.2/croppie.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/croppie/2.6.2/croppie.min.js"></script>
    <div class="container">
        <br />
        <h3 align="center">Image Crop & Upload using JQuery with PHP Ajax</h3>
        <br />
        <br />
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">Select Profile Image</div>
            <div class="panel-body" align="center">
                <input type="file" name="upload_image" id="upload_image" accept="image/*" />
                <br />
                <div id="uploaded_image"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="uploadimageModal" class="modal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Upload & Crop Image</h4>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12 text-center">
                            <div id="image_demo" style="margin-top:30px"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12" style="padding-top:30px;">
                            <button class="btn btn-success crop_image">Crop & Upload Image</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $image_crop = $('#image_demo').croppie({
                enableExif: true,
                viewport: {
                    width: '100%',
                    height: 800,

                },
                boundary: {
                    width: '100%',
                    height: 846
                }
            });

            $('#upload_image').on('change', function() {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function(event) {
                    $image_crop.croppie('bind', {
                        url: event.target.result
                    }).then(function() {
                        console.log('jQuery bind complete');
                    });
                }
                reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
                $('#uploadimageModal').modal('show');
            });

            $('.crop_image').click(function(event) {
                $image_crop.croppie('result', {
                    type: 'canvas',
                    size: 'viewport'
                }).then(function(response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "upload.php",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: {
                            "image": response
                        },
                        success: function(data) {
                            $('#uploadimageModal').modal('hide');
                            $('#uploaded_image').html(data);
                        }
                    });
                })
            });

        });

    </script>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: hugo, desculpe a demora para lhe responder, mas estive corrido! Então realmente o modal ficará responsivo, mas isso acaba influenciando no crop da imagem, onde ele ficará do tamanho que a janela estivar e não do tamanho definido no viewport o que não pode acontecer, pois como comentei o crop deve ser feito em 1747px independente do tamanho da janela. O que tem que acontecer é que a imagem deve se adequar como normalmente é feio com uma imagem com width 100% dentro de um container, porém quando acontecer o crop deve ser feito pelo tamanho definido no viewport.